# JavaFX Stage not fully loaded

Tags: javafx

I have this whole mess of Controls and Transitions in the Scene, and whenever an error or message is made, I call `FormBuilder.say(String x)`.

The sample included doesn't error as much, because it's empty. But when all the stuff are active, the pop up from `FormBuilder.say(String x)` comes out as a mess.

If I wait long enough, attempt to interact, or if I minimize then restore the Stage, it loads properly. But many times, it's just blank.

My laptop runs Ubuntu 15.10, with approx 2GB RAM. No Video Card.

Included is a screen cap of the messy picture.[image: Sample with error]

Included is the code that's affected during the bug. I've striped out some of the less suspected parts. (EDITED)

```
 package solo;

 import javafx.animation.Animation;
 import javafx.animation.TranslateTransition;
 import javafx.application.Application;
 import javafx.beans.value.ChangeListener;
 import javafx.beans.value.ObservableValue;
 import javafx.geometry.Pos;
 import javafx.scene.Scene;
 import javafx.scene.control.Button;
 import javafx.scene.layout.Pane;
 import javafx.scene.layout.VBox;
 import javafx.scene.paint.Color;
 import javafx.scene.shape.Rectangle;
 import javafx.scene.text.Text;
 import javafx.stage.Stage;
 import javafx.stage.StageStyle;
 import javafx.stage.Window;
 import javafx.util.Duration;

 public class FormBuilder extends Application{

    Stage ps;
        public FormBuilder(){

        }
        public void begin(String[] args){
            launch(args);
        }

        public void start(Stage primaryStage) {
            ps = primaryStage;
            ps.setTitle("E-VIL v0.0");

            ps.setScene(new Scene(scene(), 800, 600));
            ps.show();
        }

        public void say(String things){
            Stage stage = new Stage(StageStyle.UTILITY);
            stage.initOwner(ps);
            Text text = new Text(things);
            Button btn = new Button("Okay");
            btn.setOnAction(e -> {stage.close();});
            VBox pane = new VBox(text,btn);
            pane.setAlignment(Pos.TOP_CENTER);
            text.setLayoutY(12);
            pane.autosize();
            stage.setScene(new Scene(pane));
            stage.sizeToScene();
            stage.setOnShown(e -> {stage.requestFocus();});
            stage.showAndWait();
        }
        public Pane scene(){
            Pane pn = new Pane();
            Button btn = new Button("Say Something");
            btn.setOnAction(e->{FormBuilder.this.say("Something");});
            btn.setLayoutX(0);
            btn.setLayoutY(10);
            pn.getChildren().add(btn);

            pn.sceneProperty().addListener(new ChangeListener<Scene>(){
                @Override
                public void changed(ObservableValue<? extends Scene> arg0, Scene arg1, Scene arg2) {
                    System.out.println("new Scene");
                    if(arg2 != null)
                    arg2.windowProperty().addListener(new ChangeListener<Window>(){
                        @Override
                        public void changed(ObservableValue<? extends Window> observable, Window oldValue,
                                Window newValue) {
                            System.out.println("new window");
                            if(newValue != null){
                                Rectangle rect = new Rectangle(0,30,300,300);
                                rect.setFill(Color.RED);
                                pn.getChildren().add(rect);

                                Rectangle box = new Rectangle(30,60,50,50);
                                TranslateTransition tt = new TranslateTransition(Duration.seconds(1), box);
                                tt.setByX(160);
                                tt.setByY(160);
                                tt.setAutoReverse(true);
                                tt.setCycleCount(Animation.INDEFINITE);
                                pn.getChildren().add(box);
                                tt.play();

                            }
                        }

                    });
                }

            });

            return pn;
        }
 }
```

---

```
 package solo;

 public class Main {
    public static void main(String args[]){
        FormBuilder fb = new FormBuilder();
        fb.begin(args);
    }

 }
```

Comment: Your code works every time for me.

Comment: Darn... I'll add the animation then, and see if I can make the error happen again. Sorry for the delay, but I'm gonna have to dig through some code first.

Comment: @James_D I have edited the code, and have tested it. The error occurs again.

Comment: Works every time for me too.

Comment: If it doesn't happen for you, I'm guessing it's more of a hardware problem then. Try clicking the button many times. Mine starts glitching at around 3-5 clicks.

Comment: Still works... what OS and JDK version are you using?

Comment: I use Lubuntu 15.10, 32bit. I'm running Eclipse Mars. Project uses JavaSE-1.8. Installed in laptop is: openjdk version "1.8.0_66-internal"